# Formatting Bootstrap carousel for twitter feed

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am pulling tweets into a bootstrap carousel, but they aren't going into their own individual slides. I am creating the elements for the `.item` and `.carousel-content`, but having trouble getting the tweets to split into their own slides. What am I missing that all of the tweets are going into one slide?

**HTML**

```
<div class="parser" style="display: none"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var Twitter = {};

Twitter.callback = function (jsonP) {
    //console.log("json", jsonP);
    var parser = $(".parser"),
        container = $(".container"),
        tweets,
        i,
        createItem = function (item, index) {

            var div = $('<div class="item' + ((index === 0) ? ' active' : '') + '"></div>'),
                divInner = $('<div class="carousel-content"></div>');
            //console.log('<div class="item'+((index === 0)?' active':'') +'"></div>');
            div.append(divInner.append($(item).children()));

            div.append($(item).children());

            return div;
        };

    parser.html(jsonP.body);



    tweets = $('.h-feed').children('li');

    for (i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        container.append(createItem(tweets[i], i));
    }


}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var jp = document.createElement("script");
    jp.src = "https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/506829210191552512?&lang=en&callback=Twitter.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd=0.3450709420721978";
    var hd = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    hd.appendChild(jp);

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/gXN2u/331/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the container was set to the wrong div. It should have been `container = $(".carousel-inner")`